# How to create a dual-authentication HTTPS client in Python without (L)GPL libs?

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Both the client and the server are internal, each has a certificate signed by the internal CA and the CA certificate. I need the client to authenticate the server's certificate against the CA certificate it has. It also should send its certificate to the server for authentication.

The *urllib2* manual says that server authentication is not performed. *PycURL* is a natural alternative but its license is not approved yet. I would also prefer not having to compile the library from the source code but to use RPM instead.

I went over a bunch of libraries like *requests*, *httplib2* and don't see what I need. There is also the *ssl* module but I don't feel like implementing http myself if I don't absolutely must.

Python 2.6 on RHEL 5.7

Comment: I am facing almost similar problem and I solve it by letting Apache do all SSL lifting

Comment: @Mikko - my problem is on the client side which a Python utility

Comment: Aha. Sorry did not get that on the first time :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, the winner (almost) is [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) v0.7. Starting from this version it supports SSL certificate authentication. Here's the sample code

```
import httplib2
client = httplib2.Http(ca_certs='ca.crt')
client.add_certificate(key='client_private_key.pem', cert='cert_client.pem', domain='')
headers, resp = client.request(query)
```

Note the `domain=''` parameter, it didn't work for me otherwise.

PS. unfortunately this simple solution does not work for me as I forgot to mention additional requirement - having RPM installation for RHEL 5.7 & Python 2.6.

Comment: I wish, I could upvote this answer more. I tried python requests, urllib3 all without sucess. But this works!. I've found a new fav library.

Answer (score 3):

[Twisted Python](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is a library that may do what you need although I'm not sure if the MIT license fits what you want.  GPL is a pretty specific license and hopefully you didn't mean "all open source licenses."

For SSL examples, see http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html.  The last couple examples on that page are particularly relevant based on your description. Twisted uses [PyOpenSSL](https://launchpad.net/pyopenssl) ([docs](http://packages.python.org/pyOpenSSL/)) which is licensed with the Apache license.  You might consider using PyOpenSSL directly as well.

Comment: thanks. It looks interesting but seems an an overkill for me - I need one simple request and response, so using reactor would be over-engineering in this case.

Comment: Perhaps. If you feel the framework is too much to bite off in one chunk, use the PyOpenSSL library (link above) and do it by hand.  I think you'll find the level of effort to be similar in either case though.

Comment: I am going to try the `httplib2` which looks suitable and simple. I'll update here how it went

Answer (score 3):

Update: If [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) didn't support client-side certificates before, [it supports it now](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification), provided the local cert's private key (if any) is unencrypted:

```
>>> requests.get('https://FOO.BAR.BAZ/', cert=('/path/client.cert', '/path/client.key'))
<Response [200]>
```