# Interfacing to the LinkPoint API with Python - Sending XML Over SSL with Authentication

Tags: python, xml, api, https, linkpoint

I'm trying to make a successful connection to the LinkPoint gateway using Python.  For those of you unfamiliar with their API you get a `.pem` file you use for authentication purposes.

I'm having trouble using this file and creating a secure connection over SSL.

According to their API documentation (which leaves a lot to be desired, btw) I believe the configuration should look similar to below:

```
HOST = 'secure.linkpt.net'
API_URL = 'https://secure.linkpt.net/lpc/servlet/lppay'
PORT = 1129
cert_key = my_cert_key.pem
```

Using this information and a valid `XML` string how can I create this connection?

I'm pretty new to `HTTP` connections in Python.  I've successfully implemented connections with other APIs using a `POST` with `urllib2`.  Naturally, my first attempt started with a similar approach hoping I could stumble on to a solution.

Something like:

```
headers = { 'User-Agent'     : 'Rico',
            'Content-type'   : 'text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"',
            'Content-length' : len(self.xml_string),
          }

# POST to First Data (Link Point)
req = urllib2.Request(API_URL, self.xml_string, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
self.handleResponse(response.read())
```

I had little hopes this would work as I didn't provide anything about the `cert_key` or the `PORT`.

After this attempt I tried to use a similar approach as I found from a solution from another [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093289/how-to-create-a-dual-authentication-https-client-in-python-without-lgpl-libs) post.  Unfortunately I wasn't able to get far with this as I don't have `ca_certs` or `cert` files (that I know of).

I've tried to use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) but can't find the documentation/examples for me to make sense of it.

I've also tried to use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), and I really hoped I could do something with this but this feels like trying to open a door with a wrecking ball.  It just feels like overkill to me.  I just need a simple connection/request/response...this seems overly complicated for that.

My next attempt was going to be [PycURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/), but have confronted enough despair during this process I thought I'd come here to see if someone had some good suggestions before diving into this.

If you think I should re-visit one of these tools please let me know.  I didn't spend a great deal of time with any of these - just enough to get my feet wet.  If you could also point me to a good example or detailed documentation that would be fantastic.

Also, I'd prefer not to use the standard `SSL` library to build the connection myself - I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I was able to use to get a valid connection was using `httplib` as follows:

```
import httplib

HOST = 'staging.linkpt.net'
API_URL = '/lpc/servlet/lppay'
PORT = 1129
CERTFILE = 'my_cert_file.pem'

headers = { 'User-Agent'     : 'Rico',
            'Content-type'   : 'text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"',
            'Content-length' : len(xml_str),
          }

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(HOST, PORT, cert_file = CERTFILE)
conn.putrequest("POST", API_URL)
conn.putheader(headers)
conn.endheaders()
conn.send(xml_str)
response = conn.getresponse()
```

I have yet been able to generate a valid request.  Apparently I interpreted the API documentation incorrectly and keep getting a `Malformed or unrecognized request.` but at least I'm making the connection.

I'll update this answer if I'm able to determine more useful information regarding this subject.

UPDATE:  A Link Point customer service employee told me I was using old API documentation.  I've since tried with the newer version and still cannot connect.  I can't even get a response from their server.  This is no longer a possible solution to this problem.

UPDATE 2: I was able to solve this problem in another post [SSL Connection Using .pem Certificate With Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586880/ssl-connection-using-pem-certificate-with-python)

Enjoy!