# SSL Connection Using .pem Certificate With Python

Tags: python, ssl, pem

I'm trying to establish successful communication over an HTTPS connection using authentication.  I'm using Python 2.7 w/ Django 1.4 on Ubuntu 12.04.

The API documentation I'm following has specific requirements for authentication.  Including the `Authentication` header you'll find below and sending certificate information.

This is the code:

```
import httplib
import base64

HOST = 'some.host.com'
API_URL = '/some/api/path'

username = '1234'
password = '5678'

auth_value = base64.b64encode('WS{0}._.1:{1}'.format(username, password))
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'keys/')
pem_file = '{0}WS{1}._.1.pem'.format(path, username)

xml_string = '<some><xml></xml><stuff></stuff></some>'

headers = { 'User-Agent'     : 'Rico',
            'Content-type'   : 'text/xml',
            'Authorization'  : 'Basic {0}'.format(auth_value),
          }



conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(HOST, cert_file = pem_file)
conn.putrequest("POST", API_URL, xml_string, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/views.py" in processPayment
  37.         processCreditCard = ProcessCreditCard(token, postHandling)
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/credit_card_handling.py" in __init__
  75.             self.processGateway()
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/credit_card_handling.py" in processGateway
  95.         gateway = Gateway(self)
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/first_data.py" in __init__
  37.         self.postInfo()
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/first_data.py" in postInfo
  245.         response = conn.getresponse()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in getresponse
  1018.             raise ResponseNotReady()

Exception Type: ResponseNotReady at /processPayment/
Exception Value:
```

Why am I getting this error?

UPDATE 1:
I've been using the `.pem` file they gave me (Link Point Gateway) but have read that the certificate file should contain both the certificate and the RSA private key.  Is that correct?  I tried to send a `.pem` file containing both and received the following error:

```
    Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/views.py" in processPayment
  37.         processCreditCard = ProcessCreditCard(token, postHandling)
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/credit_card_handling.py" in __init__
  75.             self.processGateway()
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/credit_card_handling.py" in processGateway
  95.         gateway = Gateway(self)
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/first_data.py" in __init__
  37.         self.postInfo()
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/first_data.py" in postInfo
  251.         conn.request('POST', self.API_URL, self.xml_string, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in request
  958.         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_request
  992.         self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in endheaders
  954.         self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_output
  814.         self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in send
  776.                 self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in connect
  1161.             self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py" in wrap_socket
  381.                      ciphers=ciphers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py" in __init__
  141.                                         ciphers)

Exception Type: SSLError at /processPayment/
Exception Value: [Errno 336265225] _ssl.c:351: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
```

I can't tell if this is a step forward or backward.

UPDATE 2:
I've tried to pass both a certificate file and a key file when creating the connection object.

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(HOST, cert_file = pem_file, key_file = key_file)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/views.py" in processPayment
  37.         processCreditCard = ProcessCreditCard(token, postHandling)
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/credit_card_handling.py" in __init__
  75.             self.processGateway()
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/credit_card_handling.py" in processGateway
  95.         gateway = Gateway(self)
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/first_data.py" in __init__
  37.         self.postInfo()
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/first_data.py" in postInfo
  252.         conn.request('POST', self.API_URL, self.xml_string, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in request
  958.         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_request
  992.         self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in endheaders
  954.         self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_output
  814.         self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in send
  776.                 self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in connect
  1161.             self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py" in wrap_socket
  381.                      ciphers=ciphers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py" in __init__
  141.                                         ciphers)

Exception Type: SSLError at /processPayment/
Exception Value: [Errno 336265225] _ssl.c:351: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
```

If I try and combine the certificate file and key file and send it as the certificate argument I receive the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would seem that some of the "higher level" libraries in Python are not equipped to handle this kind of authentication connection.  After many days of attempts I was finally able to come up with a solution going down to the socket level.

```
host = 'some.host.com'
service = '/some/api/path'
port = 443

# Build the authorization info
username = '1234'
password = '5678'
path = '/path/to/key/files/'
pem_file = '{0}WS{1}._.1.pem'.format(path, username)
key_file = '{0}WS{1}._.1.key'.format(path, username)
auth = base64.b64encode('WS{0}._.1:{1}'.format(username, password))

## Create the header
http_header = "POST {0} HTTP/1.0\nHost: {1}\nContent-Type: text/xml\nAuthorization: Basic {2}\nContent-Length: {3}\n\n"
req = http_header.format(service, host, auth, len(xml_string)) + xml_string

## Create the socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, keyfile = key_file, certfile = pem_file)
conn.connect((host, port))
conn.send(req)

response = ''
while True:
    resp = conn.recv()
    response += resp

    if (resp == ''):
        break
```

I hope someone finds this useful.  This particular implementation was to interface with Link Point Gateway with Python (not supported by First Data (Link Point)).  Talk about a nightmare this whole project has been.  haha

Anyway, for anyone having trouble using Link Point please be advised that the `.key` file they provide you is not sufficient for creating a connection in Python.

`openssl rsa -in orig_file.key -out new_file.key`

Then use the `new_file.key` instead.

Comment: Good job, but I don't understand, what was the problem, and why this solved it?